# How to add element after existing element and remove it in Linked List [Java]

Tags: java, data-structures

I am confused as how am I suppose to add element after an existing element and remove in linked list.

I am creating a method call `addAfter` and `removeLinkAfter`.
run1 and run2 is my expected outcome of the following code given. 
May i know how to solve 'addAfter' and 'removeLinkAfter' method please?
Sorry if my code is very long.

[run 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y00QD.png)

[run2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr18w.png)

```
package linkedlist1;


public class Link {

    // Set to public so getters and setters aren't needed    
    public String bookName;
    public int millionsSold;

    // This is the next pointer for my Link List
    // This is important so I have a reference to the Link that was created before it
    // Always NULL until it is connected to other links
    public Link next;

    // Constructor
    public Link (String bookName, int millionsSold){

       this.bookName = bookName;
       this.millionsSold = millionsSold;    

    }

    public void display(){

       System.out.println(bookName + " , " + millionsSold + "000,000 Sold");
    }

    public String toString(){
       return bookName;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){

    LinkList theLinkedList = new LinkList();

    theLinkedList.insertFirstLink("Lord of The Rings", 500);
    theLinkedList.insertFirstLink("Tale of the DS Students", 1);
    theLinkedList.insertFirstLink("Harry Potter", 100);
    theLinkedList.insertFirstLink("Buku Sekolah", 10);
    theLinkedList.display();

        System.out.println ("Take a peek at value of first in LinkedList: " + theLinkedList.firstLink + "\n");

        theLinkedList.find("Tale of the DS Students");

        //Removes the first book in the linked list
    theLinkedList.removeFirst();
    theLinkedList.display();

        //Removed a particular book
    theLinkedList.removeLink("Harry Potter");
    theLinkedList.display();

        //add after a particular book
        theLinkedList.addAfter("Harry Potter", "Zati Biography", 10);
        theLinkedList.addAfter("Zati Biography", "Adam Aymar Story", 90);

        // remove after a particular book
       // theLinkedList.removeLinkAfter("Buku Sekolah");
        //theLinkedList.removeLinkAfter("Lord of The Rings");
    }

}



class LinkList{

    // Reference to the first Link in list

    public Link firstLink;

    LinkList(){

        // First Link is always starts as NULL

        firstLink = null;
    }

    // Returns TRUE if LinkList 
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return (firstLink == null);
    }

    // Insert a new Link

    public void insertFirstLink (String bookName, int millionsSold){

       Link newLink = new Link(bookName, millionsSold);    // I'm the new guy in town

       // Connects the firstLink (head in town) to the newLink (new guy in town)
       newLink.next = firstLink;
       firstLink = newLink;

    }

    public Link removeFirst(){

        Link linkReference = firstLink;

    if (!isEmpty()){

        // Removes the Link from the List
        firstLink = firstLink.next;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Empty LinkedList");
    }

        return linkReference;   
    }

    // Display/Traverse Link List
    public void display(){
        Link theLink = firstLink;

    // As long as you have yet to reach the end, display Linked List
    while (theLink != null){

        theLink.display(); 
        System.out.println("Next Link: " + theLink.next);
        theLink = theLink.next;
        System.out.println();

        }
    }

    // Searching for a particular data in Linked List

    public Link find(String bookName){        
        Link theLink = firstLink;  
        if (!isEmpty()){

            // If not empty, continue searching for bookname
        // If we reach end of link list, but did not found a match, return null
        // If we found a match, get the value of next

        while (theLink.bookName != bookName)
            {
        if (theLink.next == null)
                {
                return null;
        }   
                else
                {
            theLink = theLink.next;
            }

            }
        }
            else   
                {
                    System.out.println("Empty Linked List");

                }



        return theLink;

    }


    public Link removeLink (String bookName){
        Link currentLink  = firstLink;
    Link previousLink = firstLink;

    // Keep searching as long as there is no match
        while(currentLink.bookName != bookName){
            //Checks if the link is the end
            if (currentLink.next == null){
             // Bookname not found, so break/leave the method
         return null;
            }
        else{
         previousLink = currentLink;
         currentLink  = currentLink.next;
        }
        }

    if (currentLink == firstLink){
        firstLink = firstLink.next;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Found a match!");
        System.out.println("currentLink: " + currentLink);
        System.out.println("firstLink: " + firstLink);

        previousLink.next = currentLink.next;
    }

        return currentLink;
    }

    public void addAfter(String bookName, String bookAfter, int millionsSold ) 
    {


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `java.util.LinkedList`?
Therfor you need to create a new class with `String bookName` and `int millionsSold` as types to store the book information. You also need to override the `java.lang.equals(Object o)` method of the newly created class as follows:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof MyClass) {
        if (((MyClass) bookName).equals(o.bookName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now you can use:

```
MyClass insertAfter = ...
myList.add(new MyClass("Book title", 10), myList.firstIndexOf(insertAfter) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don´t use the [LinkedList from java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)?
A linked list is not the best Structure if you need to add / remove after a node in the middle. It is a good choice for a FIFO queue.

**Linked List:**

Each node (link) has an reference to the next node (link). [In an double linked list also to the node before.] The list itself contains a reference to first node (and in some cases also to the last one).

**Insert at beginning:**

- create new node
- get the first node of the list
- set the next node of new created node to the first node of the list
- set the new created  node as first node of the list

**Insert at end:**

- create new node
- get last node of the list (by saved reference or by iterating through the list)
- add new created node as next node to the last one
- (set new reference to last node)

**Insert after x:**

- create new node
- iterate through the nodes (see code below) and geht the required node
- update the next node references of the new node and the one, you add after

*Adding after Node:*

```
public void addAfterNode(Node n, Node newNode) {
    if(n.equals(this)) {
        newNode.setNext(this.next);
        this.next = newNode;
        return this;
    } else {
        if(this.hasNext()){
            return this.next.addAfterNode(n, newNode);
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

*Adding after Index:*

```
public void addAfterIndex(int n, Node newNode) {
    return this.addAfterIndex(n, newNode, 0);
}

private void addAfterIndex(int n, Node newNode, int curPos){
    if(n == curPos) {
        newNode.setNext(this.next);
        this.next = newNode;
        return this;
    } else {
        if(this.hasNext()){
            return this.next.addAfterIndex(n, newNode, curPos++);
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

*Adding after Element:*

```
public void addAfterElement(YourClass n, YourClass newElement) {
    if(this.element.equals(n)) {
        Node newNode = new Node(newElement);
        newNode.setNext(this.next);
        this.next = newNode;
        return this;
    } else {
        if(this.hasNext()){
            return this.next.addAfterelement(n, newElement);
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Removing works the same way.

I would recommend you to use the LinkedList from java. It is well implemented and has a good documentation. Creating an own list is only usefull for education purposes.

**See also:**
Java LinkedList [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) | [Source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java)

[Wikipedia LinkedList](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_list)